# Inside a phone booth

Tags: audio, recording, filter, eq

I want to create an EQ or other approach that mimics a person inside an old style enclosed  phone booth.  Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: Is the viewer in the phone booth with them or outside the phone booth?

Comment: outside the ball-park, but…find a friend who has Altiverb or Speakerphone - both have that exact algorithm, but cost a small fortune... so I'm not saying buy it for the sake of one effect ;-))

Answer (score 1):

Put the fictional measurements of a phone booth, say 100x100x250 cm, in one of those online room mode calculators

- http://www.bobgolds.com/Mode/RoomModes.htm
- http://amroc.andymel.eu

and recreate the highest peaks with eq. It will be only half-scientific, but at least you can analyse what such a room would really do with your sound.

Answer (score 0):

I would try a couple really short delays for reflections with a boost in mid-high end frequencies (1khz shelf eq?).

Answer (score 0):

You could try playing back and recording the sounds you require in a similar space, say, a wardrobe. Obviously you'd need to use a professional speaker and the original recording would need to be of sufficient quality to avoid introducing unwanted tones or noise. Assuming it's dialogue your mainly concerned with?